# where are the other partitions?

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, kernel, partition

My laptop has windows 7, windows 8 and linux. I have by mistake changed the partition of linux from logical to primary. so after running `sudo fdisk -l` i got only:

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *    767621120 920459263 152838144 72.9G 83 Linux
```

how can I get back the other partitions please.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try programs like `gpart` or `testdisk`. But before doing anything, try to make an image of the whole disk (e.g. via `dd`), if you have another spare disk, so that things do not get worse. You could even work on this image (or another copy of it) with many recovery programs, to be sure to not touch anything accidentally.